# .htaccess rewrite causes an endless loop

Tags: .htaccess, loops, url-rewriting

I have a .htaccess code the rediredt every user on smartphone to a competible website:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://logo.artliner.co.il//mobile.html%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

This code causes an endless loop that looks like this:
http://logo.artliner.co.il//mobile.html/mobile.html/mobile.html/mobile.html/mobile.html/mobile.html/mobile.html/

Can you help me solve this and stop the loop please?
Thanks!

Comment: are all smartphone users redirect to `mobile.html`?

Comment: Yes.

Thanks Ben.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule !^mobile.html$ /mobile.html [R,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` is only applied if the request URI pattern is not exactly to `mobile.html`.

Comment: Ben, you are GENIUS. Thanks a lot!

Comment: mmmm.. Something stragne. it DID redirect me to the right URL in the mobile, but I see only text on blank white page and not the actual site.

This is how the website should look on the mobile:
http://logo.artliner.co.il/mobile.html

And this is how it looks in my smartphone:
https://i.imgur.com/nn2tCvw.png

Comment: what url you redirected?

Comment: http://logo.artliner.co.il/mobile.html (look at the pic I added), and yet I can't see the actual website, just black text on white page.

Comment: are the page same if the rewriterule not applied?

Comment: mmmm... Yes. very strange, as you can see at the desktop it looks fine.

Comment: then it is not the `RewriteRule` problem, might be the server detect the user agent and made a difference response, or some css trick setup etc..

Comment: Hi Ben, it somethimg with the .htaccess. this is how it looks like with the code you wrote in the .htaccess: https://i.imgur.com/nn2tCvw.png, and this is without the code: https://i.imgur.com/sI4ncw8.png... You have an idea?

Comment: just updated, still need to check if the url requesting the existing files or directories